# How to close all modals from different Angularjs components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

On my project, we use Angularjs 1.7 and bootstrap modals and we have a lot of components. Some components has modal. So my question is: how to close these modals when I am on different component.

Say component A, B, C has some modals open, now on app.js(main js file for angularjs) or Component D, I want to close all of these modals. How can I achieve that? I know how to close modal on A,B,C itself, but don't know how to close modals from outside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide which modal do you use, Google material, Bootstrap or other 3d party? will be helpful some code snippet

Comment: I updated the post. I am using bootstrap modal